# C# empty MYSQL table contents

Tags: c#, mysql

i need too empty some tables contents from the app i use that MySQL command system but it doesn't have command to empty tables

```
        #region Delete
        public MySqlCommand Delete(string table, string column, string value)
        {
            _command = _command.Replace("<R>", "`" + table + "`");
            _command = _command.Replace("<C>", "`" + column + "`");
            _command = _command.Replace("<V>", "'" + value + "'");
            return this;
        }
        public MySqlCommand Delete(string table, string column, long value)
        {
            _command = _command.Replace("<R>", "`" + table + "`");
            _command = _command.Replace("<C>", "`" + column + "`");
            _command = _command.Replace("<V>", value.ToString());
            return this;
        }
        public MySqlCommand Delete(string table, string column, ulong value)
        {
            _command = _command.Replace("<R>", "`" + table + "`");
            _command = _command.Replace("<C>", "`" + column + "`");
            _command = _command.Replace("<V>", value.ToString());
            return this;
        }
        public MySqlCommand Delete(string table, string column, bool value)
        {
            _command = _command.Replace("<R>", "`" + table + "`");
            _command = _command.Replace("<C>", "`" + column + "`");
            _command = _command.Replace("<V>", (value ? "1" : "0"));
            return this;
        }

        #endregion
```

anyone have any idea to empty the table, thanks

Comment: *doesn't have command to empty tables* - Yes it does: `public MySqlCommand Delete`

Comment: If you are set on using that class for every mySQL command you want to process you'll have to add another type `Clear` or similar that does `_command = new StringBuilder("DELETE FROM <R>");`

Comment: @iabbott Or for the lazy person, set both `<C>` and `<V>` to the same value.

Comment: i want to clear all table contents at once delete command use for delete a specific data from a table

Comment: @AhmedMohammed i posted my comment as an answer then

Comment: Eh... `TRUNCATE TABLE t`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are set on using that class for every mySQL command you want to process you'll have to add another type, **ClearAll** or similar that does:

```
_command = new StringBuilder("DELETE FROM <R>");
```

Then you'll have to add the code into one of the **Execute** methods (of course)